# Fast TCP exchange rate in Java

Tags: java, tcp, lag

I am making an multiplayer game in Java, and i am using a tcp connection for client/server communication. I tried to optimize the transmission by making it send packets only when there are changes in the game, googling the issue, flushing the objectstream and socket after each transmittion, and i set the setTcpNoDelay to true. But i still can see lag, and sometimes the incoming packets stall for a few seconds(sometimes forever(or a very long period that i didn't try to wait)), until another packet is sent(sounds like buffering to me).
I didn't test it over lan, just on my localhost.
I know that Minecraft is written in Java, and it works very well with minimal lag, so there must be a way to fix this...

Are there any other tips that i can implement to speed up the tcp client/server communication?

Edit: The player instance includes the player speed, so between two incoming packets the game runs the other players from last known position with the last known speed.

Comment: You've isolated reading data and writing data to separate threads on both the client and the server, right?

Comment: Yes, in fact, i have separate threads for sending, receiving, and game/server functions.

Comment: I wouldn't use an ObjectStream if you want performance.  Note; if you send a mutable object it will only be sent once and you won't see any changes made to it until you call reset(). Try using a DataOutputStream and BufferedOutputStream with flush().

Comment: The packets can go fast sometimes, but sometimes something starts jamming, and then i have toes lag issues...

Comment: The weird thing is that it works better when the client floods the server every 20 ms with data updates(by doing that, the server automatically retransmits all updated data to all players).

Comment: I got a more stable connection by doing some optimization on the server side, but still sometimes i have toes lag issues...